# Why is my Rails app trying to send an email in the development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, postfix-mta

I have followed the [instructions on this page](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/actionmailer) to get started on ActionMailer. After I tested that it can send emails from a Gmail account, I reset perform_deliveries option to false and sent a few test emails. Even though these emails shouldn't get sent, I can look at the /var/log/mail.log and see that it's still trying to send emails from smtp, and I get constant popups warning me about "operation timed out"

Here is a sample error:

```
postfix/smtp[2837]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.93.27]:25: Operation timed out
```

How can I make sure that Rails doesn't attempt to send emails when I am in the development mode? I assumed this would be automatic since I have set perform_deliveries set to false.

Comment: Where did you set your perform_deliveries config value? I assume in environments/development.rb.  Also, make sure you have restarted your server after setting that value.

Comment: Yes, it was in development.rb. I did restart the server a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` in your `development.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you using ActionMailer #deliver method and not #deliver! because last one bypass checking perform_deliveries